# Different On-clicks for programmatically added buttons

Tags: android, database, button, onclick, onclicklistener

I was looking through some topics but couldn't find exact answer or at least couldn't get it right. What happens in the code is that i create one button for each row in my database and each button is supposed to have an OnClick that sends us to another activity along with some values(each button is supposed to have different value) but in the end it seems like i get the same value for all of my buttons which makes me think that it only creates 1 view for all of the buttons.

```
Cursor przepis = bazaUzytkownikow.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM przepisy", null);
    int liczba_wierszy = przepis.getCount();
    przepis.moveToPosition(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < (liczba_wierszy/4)+1; i++) {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {


            if((przepis.moveToPosition((i*4)+j)!=false))
            {
                nrPrzepisu=(i*4)+j;
            Button btnTag = new Button(this);
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(115, 60));
            btnTag.setText(przepis.getString(przepis.getColumnIndex("nazwa")));
            btnTag.setTextSize(10);
            btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));


            btnTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View t) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent IdzPrzepis = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DodajPrzepis.class);
                    IdzPrzepis.putExtra("ID_uzytkownika", ID_uzytkownika);
                    IdzPrzepis.putExtra("nr_Przepisu", nrPrzepisu);
                    startActivity(IdzPrzepis);
                }
            });
            row.addView(btnTag);
            }
        }

       layout.addView(row);
    }
```

To make the code more clear for you - bazaUzytkownikow is my database, liczba_wierszy is the number of the rows that i got. I move the cursor to the beginning since it's where i want to start and i proceed to "cut" my data using 2 loops. I am aiming for 4 buttons in 1 row.
The part that i think doesn't work is the OnClick method where i want my button to switch activity and send nrPrzepisu which is basically adding a connection between my button and proper row in the database (In the other activity i want to set text, reading rows from database depends on which button you click).
I checked the other activity and it seems to be reading same nrPrzepisu everytime which usually equals the last value of nrPrzepisu=(i*4)+j when loops finish and it made me think that i somehow need to make different views for each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing the same object to each onClick then changing that object with the next iteration. In the end all the onClicks have the same nrPzepisu object and it is returning the value which is whatever is last in this example.

```
int nrPrzepisu = (i*4) + j;
```

This way you aren't passing the same object into all the onClicks.

Comment: I am newbie at this but I added a "final int transfer = nrPrzepisu" after that. I could copy it to my intent as well and it worked, thanks!